# Spring Boot Scheduler fixedRate has deviation with expected time period

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a sample spring boot app which calls a downstream API from scheduler method execution. I have used the `fixedRate` variable under `@Scheduled` with 3000ms value. While I run the application, the follow up executions are sometimes lesser than 3 seconds (like 2.99 or 2.84 sec). Can I know what needs to be changed in the code in order to have the method executed properly. Please find below the code:

SchedulerDemoApplication

```
package edu.demo.scheduler;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class SchedulerDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>edu.demo.scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>SchedulerDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SchedulerDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`Configuration` class:

```
package edu.demo.scheduler.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;

@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.task.scheduling.pool.size}")
    int poolSize;
    
    @Bean("scheduler")
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(poolSize);
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("PoolScheduler");
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

SchedulerService.

```
package edu.demo.scheduler.component;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SchedulerService {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
    @Async("scheduler")
    public void taskScheduler() {
        
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + " Starting: " + LocalDateTime.now());
        try { Thread.sleep(5000); }catch (Exception e) {}   //  Dummy downstream call

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + " Running: " + LocalDateTime.now());
    }
    
}
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.web=DEBUG
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=5
```

Console Output:

```
PoolScheduler1 -  Starting: 2023-04-06T17:16:26.900489100
PoolScheduler3 -  Starting: 2023-04-06T17:16:29.901791600
PoolScheduler1 -  Running: 2023-04-06T17:16:31.905599700
PoolScheduler2 -  Starting: 2023-04-06T17:16:32.899475300
PoolScheduler3 -  Running: 2023-04-06T17:16:34.911002700
PoolScheduler4 -  Starting: 2023-04-06T17:16:35.891940200
PoolScheduler2 -  Running: 2023-04-06T17:16:37.911668800
PoolScheduler4 -  Running: 2023-04-06T17:16:40.900844100
```

I have tried the same code in another machine and the deviation was only of 30ms and the scheduler method was executing at 2.997 or 2.996 sec on average. So I am guessing that the deviation is dependent on hardware.

Answer (score 2):

As you obviously want to run your tasks both scheduled and multi threaded I suggest to use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which combine both concepts.

Comment: `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` has helped resolving the issue to a great extent but once in a 10 or 15 executions I still see a minor deviation. I have replaced the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` from Configuration Bean.

pool-1-thread-4 -  Starting: 2023-04-07T10:46:31.188632900 
pool-1-thread-2 -  Running: 2023-04-07T10:46:33.183812600
pool-1-thread-1 -  Starting: 2023-04-07T10:46:34.180120400

From above console output, the difference between the start of the thread-4 and thread-1 is less than 3 seconds.